# Extract text between <br > tags

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

To extract URL's I am using the following:

```
html = open('http://lab/links.html')
urls = URI.extract(html)
```

This works great.

Now I need to extract a list of URL's without the prefix http or https, which are between `<br >` tags.  Since there are no http or https tags, URI.extract doesnt work.

```
domain1.com/index.html<br >domain2.com/home/~john/index.html<br >domain3.com/a/b/c/d/index.php
```

Each unprefixed URL is between `<br >` tags.

<strike>I have been looking at this [Nokogiri Xpath to retrieve text after <BR> within <TD> and <SPAN>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019711/nokogiri-xpath-to-retrieve-text-after-br-within-td-and-span) but couldnt get it to work.</strike>

Output

```
domain1.com/index.html
domain2.com/home/~john/index.html
domain3.com/a/b/c/d/index.php
```

<strike>Intermediate solution</strike>

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://lab/noprefix_domains.html"))
doc.search('br').each do |n|
  n.replace("\n")
end
puts doc
```

I still need to strip out the rest of the HTML tags (`!DOCTYPE, html, body, p`)...

**Solution**

```
str = ""
doc.traverse { |n| str << n.to_s if (n.name == "text" or n.name == "br") }
puts str.split /\s*<\s*br\s*>\s*/
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the html source of 'http://lab/links.html'?

Comment: @DevlshOne this is not a PHP question.

Comment: What do you want as output?

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti just a list of urls without the prefix, one on each line. Also need to check and make sure no lines contain more than one url - no spaces per line (due to user input error).

Comment: please give us s sample `html` and tell us from the sample what are things you want to have? This will help us to help you out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already have a method to extract the example string you showed in your question, you can use `split` on the string:

```
str = "domain1.com/index.html<br >domain2.com/home/~john/index.html<br >domain3.com/a/b/c/d/index.php"
str.split /\s*<\s*br\s*>\s*/
#=> ["domain1.com/index.html", 
#    "domain2.com/home/~john/index.html",
#    "domain3.com/a/b/c/d/index.php"]
```

This will split the string at every `<br>` tag. It will also remove whitespace before and after the `<br>` and allow for whitespace inside the `<br>` tag, e.g. `<br >` or `< br>`. If you need to handle self-closing tags, too (e.g. `<br />`), use this regex instead:

```
/\s*<\s*br\s*\/?\s*>\s*/
```

Comment: Thx. I was trying to stay away fro regex. :-) Anyway tried this out got `undefined method ``split' for #<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x007fce6b8f39c8> (NoMethodError)` I think it may be the nokogiri response.

Comment: As i said, i assumed in my answer that you already have the string you showed in your question. If you don't, you should really update your answer with the full HTML or an example with the same structure if you cannot expose the document to the public. Otherwise, it is nearly impossible to provide you with an accurate solution.

Comment: Oh and the reason for the error is that you tried to call `split` on a  `Nokogiri::HTML::Document` instead of a `String`.

Comment: i converted to string and used split. it ended up to be much cleaner. thx, again.